Is it possible to reference and transpose each staff separately for midi output only in lilypond?
I wanted to create a setup, where I can generate a full score as well as each part and separate registers using lilypond. For the most part, my setup works fine, however I have some issues transposing the midi output for the different instruments correctly.
Here is the setup:

In my source material I always have the instrument pitch available for each part (meaning the notes the person playing a certain instrument sees)
The full score in my source material also displays the same notes, so not the concert pitch

I think it woud be relatively easy to transpose everything to concert pitch (= c), but I want to output the sheet music as is since I will probably need this setup in the future.
So the question now is, how to transpose each part in a register output or the full score output according to the instrument?
Here is what I tried so far (example with a part of the clarinet register).
\version "2.24.3"
\include "_global_definitions.ly"
\include "clarinet_eb.ly"
\include "clarinet_1.ly"
\include "clarinet_2.ly"

\header {
  instrument = "Clarinets"
}


\book {
  \bookOutputName "register_clarinets"
  \score {
    \midi {
      \context Staff = "pitch_es" {
        \transposition es 
      }
      \context Staff = "pitch_bes"{
         \transposition bes 
      }
     }
    <<
      \new StaffGroup = "StaffGroup_clarinets" <<
        \new Staff="pitch_es" {
          \set Staff.midiInstrument = "clarinet"
          \clarinet_eb
        }
        \new Staff="pitch_bes" {
          \set Staff.midiInstrument = "clarinet"
          \clarinet_two
        }
      >>
    >>
  }
}

This does transpose something (i have tested this with A-B sound tests), but sounds horrible so my guess is something with the context references is wrong. The actual notes in clarinet_eb and clarinet_two should be correct, I have checked those multiple times now.

What exactly does "sounds horrible" mean?

@mkrieger1 it means, I can hear that the harmonys are off and the transposition is wrong.  AFAIK midi outputs everything in 'c' , so if I output all the parts directly as midi without transposition they do not work together

So my question boils down to: can I transpose the midi output of each staff in the score corresponding to the respective instrument without changing the sheet music displayed in the pdf.

I think you will get better answers for this on [music.se]

OK, I will post the question there - just thought it would be OK here, since there are quite a lot lilypond questions here as well as a dedicated tag

IMHO it’s OK here. I myself use the Lilypond User mailing list and tend to get very good answers fast. See the contact page on lilypond.org.
